# When did Bruce organize his will and the new Bat signal?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

What do you think the timeline looked like after returning from the Pit in *The Dark Knight Rises*, specifically when and how did Bruce get his will set up and the new Bat signal put on the MCU building? I have been pondering it and would like some other suggestions.

Comment: I need to see the movie again, but my impression was that it happened after Batman "died".

Comment: It's awfully hard to edit and sign your will AFTER you "died" and stay dead.

Comment: It's been months since I saw the movie, but I don't recall *Bruce* dying - just Batman in the supposed explosion.

Answer (score 8):

He did all of this before he went to face Bane in the tunnel. When Alfred speaks to him and leaves, Bruce gets the picture. He cannot and does not want to be the Batman, but he knows that he can't walk away, leaving the city without a hero. When, however, he meets Robin - John Blake - he knows that he can hang up the cape. That's when he changes the will and fixes the autopilot. In the eyes of the city, he has to be dead. Batman has to give them everything, so that Bruce can have something.

Comment: That's a logical explanation. Is there anything in the movie or extra materials that backs up this theory?